# iPhone - Localizable.strings with double quotes escape character

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

Inside the Localizable.strings file, if I add the escape character ", the file fails the building process.

For example:

```
"Now open ""Phone"" application" = "Maintenant ouvert ""Téléphone"" application";
```

I get an error due to this line. If commented out, it works just fine.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You have to escape the quote marks with a backslash:

```
"Now open \"Phone\" application" = "Maintenant ouvert \"Téléphone\" application";
```

Comment: Beware! During importing Xcode will remove all these double quotes! **Version 6.4 (6E35b)**